# how to prevent to change colour while list view scroll

Tags: flutter

I have created a demo

I have set colour as random for each container of list view, so it changes colours whenever I scroll ,

I want to prevent changing colour while scrolling,

Like if first container colour is red then it should b not changed until I restart app,

I placed print statement inside build method...but it showing only once, than why container's colour get changed,

if it rebuilds, it should execute print statement more than one time

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 10,
          itemBuilder: (context,index){
        return Container(
          height: 200,
          color: Color.fromRGBO(Random().nextInt(255), Random().nextInt(255), Random().nextInt(255), 1),
       );
      }),
    );
  }
```

Comment: With that code, you can't. You need to already have a list of colors before hand and pass the index (position) of that list of colors to keep the same one. ListView, GridView, etc recycle your current widget when gets out of focus, therefore, your Random will run again and generate a new color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ListView.builder` items won't be alive for performance matter, every time you scroll, it build those item. try this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var colorList =  List<Color>.generate(10, (index) => Color.fromRGBO(Random().nextInt(255), Random().nextInt(255), Random().nextInt(255), 1)).toList();
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: colorList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context,index){
        return Container(
          height: 200,
          color: colorList[index],
       );
      }),
    );
  }
```

Comment: What if I don't have any idea about number of containers in advance,

Comment: how do you get that nummber?

Comment: okay, I got it now..Thanks

Comment: let say you have a testList and use it to build ListView. so instead of using 10 use testList.length.

Comment: If it was helpful please approve it so other people find it easer.